# Getstatusoutput function returns a value doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I use a **Django** application, where the view.py file does a call to changes_to_test2 function, which is inside of config.py file located in different folder to view.py.

The code is:

- view.py file:

  ```
  def test1(request):
           import commands
           command = "config.py --action=changes_to_test2"
           (status, output) = commands.getstatusoutput(command)
           print 'Output %s' %output
  ```

The print displays:

```
    Output sh: config.py: command not found
```

So never enters the other function, any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to run a command in Request Response cycle of Python. Consider using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) This will allow you to run command asynchronously. Also you might want to use absolute path some thing like "/usr/bin/python /path/to/config.py ..."

Comment: I put absolute path and 'output' is equal to "No such file or directory". I have also tried to import the file, but does not work.